# How to create a second distinct pull request from a GitHub fork?

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a [GitHub fork](https://github.com/noloader/botan). I used it to [create a pull request](https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/1014) against [upstream](https://github.com/randombit/botan/).

I'm trying to work on a second pull request. I don't want the second pull request to cross pollinate into the first pull request.

How do I configure things so I can work on the second pull request without contaminating the first full request?

---

The obvious answer (for me) is to create a second clone. GitHub does not allow that.

The next obvious answer (for me) is to create a branch. But Git does not allow me to configure it. I'm not allowed to create a branch and set its origin to my GitHub clone.

---

Here's the error when attempting to create a branch. Notice the `pull` fails, and I am not allowed to set its origin to my fork:

```
$ git checkout -b arm-aes
Switched to a new branch 'arm-aes'
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=<remote>/<branch> arm-aes
```

Now try to fix it:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/noloader/botan.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/noloader/botan.git (push)
upstream        https://github.com/randombit/botan (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/randombit/botan (push)
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=https://github.com/noloader/botan.git
error: the requested upstream branch 'https://github.com/noloader/botan.git' does not exist
...
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=https://github.com/noloader/botan
error: the requested upstream branch 'https://github.com/noloader/botan' does not exist
...
```

Comment: What error are you facing while creating a new branch from your upstream remote on your forked repo?

Answer (score 2):

> But Git does not allow me to configure it. I'm not allowed to create a branch and set its origin to my GitHub clone.

Sure it does:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b newbranch upstream/master
```

Make sure you have a git remote `upstream` referencing the original repository (the one you have forked).

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

Comment: I don't have commit rights to `upstream/master` (someone else's GitHub). I only have commit rights to `origin` (my GitHub).

Comment: @jww No problem. I have edited the answer with the command you need to have upstream commits. Make sure to reference the original repo, not your fork.